# Setting properties using Unity XML

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library

I want to set the Entity Framework ObjectContext in a repository class - the ObjectContext being a property of the repository.

I am using Unity XML configuration:

```
<register type="IUsersRepository" mapTo="SqlUsersRepository" >
  <property name="MyObjectContext">
    <value value="Per-Request" typeConverter="ObjectContextTypeConverter" />
  </property>
</register>
```

The ObjectContextTypeConverter interprets the value of the property - in this case "Per-Request" - and uses an ObjectContext stored in HttpContext.Current.Items (a per request collection in asp.net).

The ObjectContextTypeConverter.ConvertFrom method is only called once when the Unity configurations is loaded in the Application_Start method of the Global.asax file. Yet when I try to resolve an interface using Unity - the ConvertFrom method won't be called again.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you're setting it as a value. You can set it as a dependency:

```
<property name="MyObjectContext">
    <dependency />
</property>
```

and inject the context through an in injection factory:

```
Container.RegisterType<ObjectContext>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => GetTheContextInstance()));
```

Comment: You can actually shorten this to just <property name="MyObjectContext" />. dependency is assumed if nothing else is specified.